# Change AltGr to Ctrl

Tags: keyboard, configuration, keyboard-layout, emacs

I'm starting to use Emacs, and as any (Emacs) user should know, you constantly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. However, in my current layout, the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is too far away to be used constantly, and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is in the perfect position.

Is there any way to make <kbd>AltGr</kbd> behave as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and be able to change that behaviour easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste this on terminal to do the change:
`xmodmap -e 'keycode 108 = Control_R' && xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_R'`

and this to undo:
`xmodmap -e 'keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift'`

Also you can check the manuals of "xev" and "xmodmap" for more information.

Comment: The code to undo it works, but the change code just makes AltGr unusable. thanks anyway

Comment: I think I have fixed it ;-)